# accordion banner rotator

Tags: wpf, accordion, banner, rotator

I want to achieve something similar to this one  but in wpf not jquery:
http://activeden.net/item/xml-horizontal-vertical-accordion-banner-rotator/full_screen_preview/127714?ref=premiumtemplates&clickthrough_id=27852933&redirect_back=true

I have tried a good bunch of different methods, still i haven't got it to work.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? for example, what controls to use, etc. I am using the MVVM approach, as in all of my projects.
I think wpf is very very powerful, so this shouldn't be too complicated...
Ah, and the animation stuff within the content is out of scope of my question.
I only want to have that navigation stuff between those different contents like in the link bellow.

Best Regards
rosch

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use the already supplied accordion from the toolkit by the codeplex ... http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. Two points against this one: 1.) i know this one but many people say it's a buggy toolkit and it's abandoned by microsoft... 2.) more important: If you look at my sample link, you can see that it is no classical accordion. they use a zindex or something to make it more like a stack of paper or something

Comment: @user873164, are you sure toolkit is buggy? and even if it is, you get the source code from codeplex. You can always get the design and improvise.